# Cannot delete or update a parent row, foreign key constraint fails

Tags: php, mysql

I'm getting an error saying "Cannot delete or update a parent row, foreign key constraint fails." when I'm trying to update the values in the team table. What am I doing wrong?

```
$createTeam ="CREATE TABLE Team(
    teamName VARCHAR(30) not null,
    division VARCHAR(30) not null,
    photo VARCHAR(30),
    primary key(teamName, division)
    )
    engine=innodb";


$createParticipant ="CREATE TABLE Participant(
    participantName VARCHAR(30) not null,
    techniqueResult DOUBLE(10,2),
    trickResult INT(10),
    teamName VARCHAR(30) not null,
    division VARCHAR(30) not null,
    primary key (participantName),
    foreign key (teamName, division) references Team(teamName, division)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    )
    engine=innodb";




$updateTeam = "UPDATE Team SET teamName = '$newTeamName' , division = '$newDivision' WHERE teamName = '$oldTeamName' AND division ='$oldDivision'";
```

Comment: You are changing the primary key value (i.e teamName, division) in the Team table while there are records in the Participant table with that value as a foreign key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to re-think your schema.

`Team` and `Division` seems like they should be two separate entities with their own IDs.

Now depending on your business model, if a `Participant` can only be in one `Team` and one `Division` then you simply add two foreign keys in Participant to reference `Team` and `Division` respectively.

If a `Participant` can be in more that one `Teams` and/or `Divisions` you need to introduce a conceptual Entity `DivisionTeamParticipant` that will contain multiple rows of foreign keys for `Team`, `Division` and `Participant`.

EDIT @paulF

If your hierarchy is strict than it should be: `Division` -> `Team` -> `Participant`. So you would only need a foreign key in `Team` to reference `Division` and one in `Participant` to reference Team.

Comment: Or it could be the Participant is in a Team which is in a Division, so the Participant has a foreign key relating to the Team and the Team has a foreign key relating to the Division.